# Recovering evince session in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: data-recovery, logging, ubuntu-16.04, evince

**How can I recover documents which were open in Evince prior to a system crash in Ubuntu 16.04?** Ideally, I would like to find a list of files which were open just before the crash. At the least, I would like to find some sort of history.

I did a crash simulation on another computer and found out that after opening evince after an unexpected shutdown it does offer a list of "recently viewed filed". **Where is this list of recently opened (in Evince) files stored in Ubuntu 16.04?** Can I also extract the dates when each document was opened or at least the order in which they had been opened?

I tried using *gvfs-info*, but the result produced looked rather unsystematic: it both showed files which were opened a long time ago, but never recently, and did not show files which were opened during the crashed session. **Is there a more efficient way of using *gvfs* for my purpose?**

Comment: Could try searching all files in your home for some of the specific filenames, with grep for example

Comment: @Xen2050: Thank you for the very good suggestion! It looks like there is a hope to recover the previous session by looking more carefully in `gvfs-metadata` and `.cache/thumbnails/large/` I am more hopeful about the latter, because the cache files are date-stamped. Do you know the rules for creating those thumbnails? Are they created every time a new document is opened in Evince or another application? When are they deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Evince 3.18.2 (which is the version that comes with the current Ubuntu 16.04) uses Gtk's mechanism of storing recently-used files in `.local/share/recently-used.xbel` .

You can either read this XML file directly, or use Gtk methods to interpret it, for example, using Python: `python2 -c "import gtk; print('\n'.join([o.get_uri() for o in gtk.RecentManager().get_items() if o.get_mime_type()=='application/pdf']))"`

See the [GNOME documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkrecentinfo.html) for documentation of the latter method (along with ways to get timestamp of when the file was last visited etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, in my case, _recently-used.xbel_ is almost empty even though there had been a dozen of pdf's open at the time of the crash. The crash, by the way, happened when the laptop's battery completely discharged and somehow failed to suspend.

Comment: Hmm. So you are saying evince shows lots of files as "recently viewed", but `recently-used.xbel` is almost empty? In this case, I'm stumped.

Comment: I am sorry. Your answer is definitely correct. I just checked on another computer and indeed Evince writes quite a lot of history into `recently-used.xbel`. On that computer it shows "recently viewed" files. However, I am much more interested in Evince on another laptop which crashed because of the battry discharge. On this laptop `recently-used.xbel` is unfortunately empty and I hesitate launching Evince. I actually do not know if it will show any "recently viewed" files there.

Comment: Maybe I can use Zeitgeist? In fact, it contains a ton of data. I just do not know how to handle it. More specifically, I do not know how to transform Zeitgeist's "timestamp" into human-readable date. Or maybe some binary file can help?

Comment: In my case `recently-used.xbel` is filled to the brim with jpg files and no search results for "pdf". I've been browsing a folder of photos with `eog` before. This design decision is sooo fucked up, as to be on par with linux' file type detection